# Cypher import of CSV with array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having trouble importing a CSV with an array into neo4j 2.2.0 using Cypher

Having read about the "CSV header format" (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool-header-format.html),
I created this file:

```
name:ID,species,images:string[]
1,Tortula muralis,1.jpg;2.jpg;3.jpg
2,Anthoceros agrestis,6.jpg
3,Marchantia polymorpha,4.jpg;5.jpg
```

I tried:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/home/hannes/temp/bryo' AS line
CREATE (a:Bryophyte)
SET a=line
```

The import itself works. I get three new nodes. If I then print all Broyphyte nodes, the property "image" seems to be one string, not an array.

Not enough reputation to post a pic, sorry...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are mixing up two things.

For the import tool that you refer to, the import works with

```
bin/neo4j-import --into test.db --nodes bryo.csv
```

Whereas for [LOAD CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) you'd use a normal header and do the conversions in Cypher:

```
id,species,images
1,Tortula muralis,1.jpg;2.jpg;3.jpg
2,Anthoceros agrestis,6.jpg
3,Marchantia polymorpha,4.jpg;5.jpg
```

I tried:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/home/hannes/temp/bryo' AS line
CREATE (a:Bryophyte {id:line.id, name:line.name,
                     images:split(line.images,",")})
```

Comment: Cool. You're the chap from the youtube video! Danke, Michael.

Comment: @michael-hunger shouldn't it be `images:split(line.images,";")}` (as the images field delimiter is ';'...?)